# Width in percentage not working after jQuery resizing it's parent

Tags: css, jquery-ui, width, jquery-ui-dialog, autoresize

I have a div which I want to be 100% width of it's parent dialog.

```
#content {
    width: 100%;
    color:white;
    background: red;
}
```

It should this property if I manually resize the dialog, however after manually resizing, if i use the `animate()` on the dialog, it will keep the old-resized width.

The same applies to height.

[HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/7gC37/) is a good jsFiddle which better explains the problem.

How can I have the div keeping it's proportions?

How does jQuery update the width and height (when I manually resize) maintaining the proportions?

**EDIT:**

---

I wanted the gray background to be filling the whole dialog no matter what. Here is my updated jsfiddle demonstrating this: http://jsfiddle.net/Esh5h/1/

**EDIT 2:**

---

I've found a functional but very ugly way of accomplishing it: [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/Esh5h/2/)

The trick is resizing both the dialog and its `.children(".ui-dialog-content")`

**EDIT 3:**

---

Can't I just replicate the exact same function that jQuery uses to resize it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I looked at this again and inspecting the elements it is now clear to me what is happening.

As soon as you manually re-size the dialog jQuery injects a `style` attribute with fixed values, similar to this:

```
<div id="dialog" style="width: 376px; min-height: 99px; height: 282px;" class="ui-dialog-content ui-widget-content" scrolltop="0" scrollleft="0">
</div>
```

Then when you animate it the style interfere with your intended result.

Removing the `style` attribute before you animate seems to be working, similar to this:

```
$("#content").click(function () {
    $("#dialog").attr("style", "").dialog("widget").animate({
        width: $(document).width() -100,
        height: $(document).height() -100,
        left: 0,
        top: 0
    }, 150);
});
```

---

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/Esh5h/) - Moving `left` and `top` to the bottom

---

**Edit**

That `style` attribute will keep giving you issues. After removing it, when then again manually re-sizing it injects them again, messing with your expected results.

The only way I found to get around this is to keep remivng them on resize:

```
$("#dialog").on("dialogresize", function(){
    $(this).attr("style", "");
});
```

**Edit**

> I wanted the gray background to be filling the whole dialog no matter
>   what.

That seems to be an issue with your CSS selector.

Change this:

```
.ui-dialog .ui-dialog-content {
    background : #cacaca;
}
```

to this:

```
.ui-dialog {
    background : #cacaca;
}
```

In addition you still have the issue that the injected style attributes will mess up your intended styles and using the above mentioned code which remove the style attribute on re-size as well as when you animate fixes that.

---

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/Esh5h/3/) - Gray background fills dialog and injected style attribute removed at all times

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/f7aqT/) - Same as above but without the `empty-container` element

---

Comment: That does not work if you re-size the dialog to be smaller and then click on the content.

Comment: @Aiias: I didn't test this right, my apologies. The issue is that jQuery injects a `style` attribute when you manually re-size the dialog. Removing it before you apply your animation seems to work. I have update my answer accordingly.

Comment: Those in-line styles jQuery injects keep going to cause issues though every time you try to re-size. I have edited my answer again with a small work-around. Not sure if jQuery dialog has a native option you can set to stop applying those styles.

Comment: I didn't think I explained myself. I wanted to resize the "ui-dialog-content" div. That is, the one with the gray background. I have made another example at http://jsfiddle.net/Esh5h/1/. When you resize manually, it's all gray. When you click, it's getting blank padding. The blank padding is what I want to get rid of. I'll also update my question.

Comment: @TwinOneAndroid - Can you just style `#dialog` to have `height: 100%`?

Comment: @TwinOneAndroid: I have update my answer to include the information from your edits in your question. I think the latest [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/Esh5h/3/) in the last edit seems to suit now. Let me know if this is what you are looking for.

Comment: @FrançoisWahl your edit about applying the background to the .ui-dialog instead of the content is a good solution, but in my case I also use buttonpanes and custom dialogs with other names, so it should only apply to the .ui-dialog .ui-dialog-content.

Comment: Well, i'm overlapping the buttonpane background now, so with a little adaptation to my scenario it works. Thanks for the well elaborated answer.

Comment: @TwinOneAndroid: What we do in our current project is we don't use the dialog default buttons but independently inject a custom button pane when required into the main `.ui-dialog` div, following our `.ui-dialog-content`. That way the buttons are always on the bottom of the dialog. We had a hard time with trying to work with the default button pane but the custom button solution worked out well. Seems you are going down a similar route. Hope it works out as well for you too.

Comment: Yes, I'm already removing the default titlebar and injecting a custom one, so i'll just implement the buttonpane too.

Comment: This helped tremendously! Though I was having problems with the height of my dialog resetting and the scroll bar was disappearing. Ultimately I changed the line: $(this).attr("style", ""); to $(this).css({width:""}); and it worked perfectly! Thanks +1

Answer (score 0):

Unless you're trying to achieve something other than just moving and resizing the dialog, I don't think you need to reinitialize the dialog on the click event.  Notice how jQuery UI wraps your original div in a couple of new divs, so I'm grabbing the outer most element.  Try doing something like this in your Javascript:

```
$("#dialog").dialog();

$("#content").click(function () {

    $(".ui-dialog").animate({
        left: 0,
        top: 0,
        width: $(document).width() -100,
        height: $(document).height() -100
    }, 150);

});
```

Answer (score 0):

`animate({complete:function()})` is the solution. [this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Esh5h/4/) is now working.

I don't know why, but it works correct at the second click, but not at the first. [this example](http://jsfiddle.net/Esh5h/5/) with a `setTimeout()` works (with a little delay).

Answer (score 0):

You can add a callback to the animate function:

```
$("#content").click(function () {
    $("#dialog").dialog("widget").animate({
        width: $(document).width() -100,
        height: $(document).height() -100,
        left: 0,
        top: 0
    }, 150, function() { 
        $("#dialog").width($('.ui-dialog').width()); 
    });
});
```

[JsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/B5pEA/2/)